# Cannot use git while docker is up

Tags: git, docker

I have a strange situation where I can't use most git commands while Docker containers are running. As soon as I stop the Docker containers, I can use git normally again. Any suggestions for what could be causing the issue?

- Git commands that I can't use while Docker is up: `checkout`, `add`, `commit`, `rebase`
- Git commands that I can still use: `branch`

Errors:

```
$ git checkout master
fatal: Unable to create '/Users/me/project/.git/index.lock': Operation not permitted
```

```
$ git rebase -i head~2
error: could not create temporary .git/rebase-merge: Operation not permitted
```

```
$ git pull
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'ORIG_HEAD': cannot lock ref 'ORIG_HEAD': Unable to create '/Users/me/project/.git/ORIG_HEAD.lock': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile and preferably the structure of your project?

Comment: do you mean run git commands **within** or **outside** container?

Comment: @LeiYang I mean running git commands outside of the container, on my local machine

Comment: are you able to create files under `/Users/me/project/.git/`? when docker running?

Comment: @JechChua I can't share the Dockerfile because of confidentiality reasons, but it's a rather involved Rails project with a Rails server container as well as nginx, elasticsearch, redis, and mysql containers.

Comment: @LeiYang I got this error: `touch: ./.git/test.txt: Operation not permitted`. I tried the same operation while Docker containers were stopped, and got no errors.

Comment: does this issue occur when you run **any** image, or just some **specific** image? i strongly suggest you try run some other very simple dockers.

Comment: @LeiYang Good point. I tried running a random Docker image and git was fine. That means it's an incompatibility with the Docker containers for the project :(

Comment: i doubt whether that specific container is using some **volumns mount to your local git directory(though unlikely)**. that's why @JechChua asks for the docker file. now it's your response to make a docker file that both reproducible and remove all sensitive information.

Comment: Makes sense, I appreciate the help so far

Comment: "Operation not permitted" is an OS-level error (EPERM) that is pretty similar to "permission denied", except that that one (EACCES) is more specific and means you don't own some file. So EPERM means the OS has placed some kind of hold on the area, and will, e.g., only let the super-user do things, or maybe not let anyone do anything because the whole thing is frozen until something happens to unfreeze it. Docker will do this to you under many conditions: https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+eperm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LeiYang pointed out, I also think your git directory is being mounted. If you're using `docker-compose.yml` you can mount your project's root directory while ignoring git by creating a secondary anonymous volume like so:

```
volumes:
  - .:/app/
  - /app/.git/
```

Although, a better approach would be to not mount your entire project's root dir but only the `src` or the directories needed for your project to run

Comment: As you speculated, the problem was that the .git folder was mounted. More specifically, the volume configuration looked almost exactly like your example, but it was missing the final slash, so that it looked like `/app/.git` instead of `/app/.git/`. I added a slash and everything seems to work now. I appreciate you and @LeiYang's help!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it's resolved. Sometimes it's the littlest things that trip us over.